# Prove inequality using continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality

Let $V(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ be the Vandermonde matrix with $\lambda_i < 0 \;\;\forall i = 1,\dots,n$ and let $r>0$. Let $\phi(\cdot):\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a global diffeomorphism.

Let $\xi :  = \phi(\widehat{x})-\phi(x)$.

Define the set $U_\lambda(r) = \{\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n s.t. \left\|V(\lambda)\xi\right\|\leq r\}$.

If $\xi \in U_\lambda(r)$ this means that
$\left\| V(\lambda)(\phi(\widehat{x})-\phi(x)) \right\| \leq r$. To have that $\xi$ is in $U_\lambda(r)$ is sufficient to ask that $\left\| \phi(\widehat{x})-\phi(x)\right\| \leq \frac{r}{\left\|V(\lambda)\right\|}$.

I want to prove that

> by continuity, there exists $\psi(\frac{r}{\left\|V(\lambda)\right\|})$ such that $\xi \in U_\lambda(r)$ if $\left\| \widehat{x}-x \right\| \leq \psi(\frac{r}{\left\|V(\lambda)\right\|})$

This fact is asserted at the end of proof of corollary 1 of https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239059276_A_Luenberger-Like_Observer_for_Nonlinear_Systems. The problem is I do not have any idea of how to show the result. I think that the statement follows from the continuity of $\phi(\cdot)$ since no particular assumption on $\psi(\cdot)$ is taken.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I tried to explain better the problem and hope this is enough.

Comment: Yes, I think it is.